# Server-Mainboard - use iGPU instead of onboard Graphics for desktop virtualization

Tags: virtualization, graphics, intel-graphics, haswell

I'm assembling the hardware for a home server and have following question:

At the moment, I've chosen the [Asrock E3C226D2I](http://www.asrockrack.com/general/productdetail.asp?Model=E3C226D2I) as Mainboard. It has an onboard "Graphics Card" by Aspeed, AST2300, but only with 2D acc. and limited resolution. So for the VGA-ouput of the Mainboard, the intern Graphics of a CPU, e.g. of a Xeon E3 1246V3, cannot be used.

But could the intern GPU of a CPU be used for an extern access, e.g. for some graphical application (not expensive, no CAD) like a virtualized desktop, viewed with a SW like VNC Viewer? So can the intern GPU be used, if the graphics output isn't the VGA of the onboard graphics?

Comment: X11 Forwarding over SSH doesn’t use remote GPUs. Neither does Microsoft RDP (excluding RemoteFx). So why would you worry about that? Please state the accurate intended use case.

Comment: I didn't know that, so the case of SSH it seems to be cleared. I mean, if in case of desktop virtualization the Server would need a GPU, right?

Comment: No, it wouldn’t. If by Desktop Virtualization you mean a VM is running with Windows or something. Only if you want acceleration for CAD or something is a (specialized!) GPU useful. Most GPUs do not support virtualization.

Comment: I dont't want to run CAD or something like this (up to now;), but in my imagination, I could pass through the intern GPU with VT-d and use it , then just in one VM, when the Desktop would need all this opacity-stuff and so....
But your answer already helped, as for just a VM with a Desktop and some simple application, I don't need a GPU :)